# Problema de struct familia em c

Tags: c, struct

Olá estou com problema nesta questão: "Escreva um programa que leia e armazene em um vetor os dados de 30
pessoas. Estes dados são o nome da pessoa, sua idade, e os nomes completos do pai e da mãe. A seguir, o programa deve identificar (e mostrar os índices) das pessoas que estão relacionadas por um parentesco avô-neto e irmão-irmão. No caso dos irmãos, deve ser informado ainda qual é o mais novo dos dois."
O código é esse

```
#include<string.h>

  #define NUM 3

struct pessoa {
  char nome[20];
  char mae[20];
  char pai[20];
  int idade;
  };

main() {
  struct pessoa vetorPessoas[NUM];
  int i;
  printf("Digite os dados de %d pessoas:\n", NUM);
  for (i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
    printf("Digite o nome da pessoa %d: ", i);
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(vetorPessoas[i].nome);
    printf("%s\n", vetorPessoas[i].nome);
    printf("Digite o nome da mae da pessoa %d: ", i);
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(vetorPessoas[i].mae);
    printf("%s\n", vetorPessoas[i].mae);
    printf("Digite o nome do pai da pessoa %d: ", i);
    fflush(stdin);
    gets(vetorPessoas[i].pai);
    printf("%s\n", vetorPessoas[i].pai);
    printf("Digite a idade da pessoa %d: ", i);
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d", &vetorPessoas[i].idade);
    printf("%d\n", vetorPessoas[i].idade);
    }
   if(!strcmp(vetorPessoas[i].pai, vetorPessoas[i].nome)){
        printf("%s e pai de %s\n", vetorPessoas[i].pai, vetorPessoas[i].pai);
   }
   if(!strcmp(vetorPessoas[i].pai, vetorPessoas[i].pai)){
        printf("Eles sao irmaos\n");
        if(vetorPessoas[i].idade > vetorPessoas[i].idade){
            printf("%s mais velho\n", vetorPessoas[i].idade);
        }
        else{
            printf("%s e mais novo\n", vetorPessoas[i].idade);
        }
    }
}
```

O problema é que ele mostra tudo mesmo quando eu não quero e gostaria de saber como posso resolver isso.

Comment: Este if: `if(!strcmp(vetorPessoas[i].pai, vetorPessoas[i].nome)){` está fora de um loop. Note que neste ponto o valor da variável `i` é `NUM`. Além disso em `if(!strcmp(vetorPessoas[i].pai, vetorPessoas[i].pai)){` você está comparando uma string com ela mesma, não tem como ela ser diferente

Comment: Eu fiz isso que vc mostrou e agora não mostra qual irmão é mais velho

Answer (score 0):

Creio que você entendeu errado meu comentário.
Tente:
Considerando que irmãos são aqueles que tem o mesmo pai e mesma mãe:

```
printf("\nIrmãos\n");
for (i=0; i<NUM-1; i++) {
    for (j=i+1; j<NUM; j++) {
        if (!strcmp(vetorPessoas[i].pai, vetorPessoas[j].pai) && !strcmp(vetorPessoas[i].mae, vetorPessoas[j].mae)){
            printf("%s é irmão de %s\n", vetorPessoas[i].nome, vetorPessoas[j].nome);
            if (vetorPessoas[i].idade < vetorPessoas[j].idade)
                printf("%s é mais novo\n", vetorPessoas[i].nome);
            else
                if (vetorPessoas[i].idade > vetorPessoas[j].idade)
                    printf("%s é mais novo\n", vetorPessoas[j].nome);
                else
                    printf("São gêmeos\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Obs: Não tratado os casos de mais de dois irmãos.

```
printf("\nAvós\n");
for (i=0; i<NUM; i++) {
    for (j=0; j<NUM; j++) {
        if (!strcmp(vetorPessoas[i].pai, vetorPessoas[j].nome)) {
            printf("%s\tAvô paterno: %s\n", vetorPessoas[i].nome, vetorPessoas[j].pai);
            printf("%s\tAvó paterna: %s\n", vetorPessoas[i].nome, vetorPessoas[j].mae);
        }
        if (!strcmp(vetorPessoas[i].mae, vetorPessoas[j].nome)) {
            printf("%s\tAvô materno: %s\n", vetorPessoas[i].nome, vetorPessoas[j].pai);
            printf("%s\tAvó materna: %s\n", vetorPessoas[i].nome, vetorPessoas[j].mae);
        }
    }
}
```